# Google sheets API permission error for writing with gspread

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm getting an error when trying to update the value of a spreadsheet via an external editor. I'm using the python library 'gspread'; I have read access to the document but when I try to update a cell I get an API error.

Here is the code (security details obscured). I've looked at other permission error solutions on stackoverflow, but they don't apply to the scenario where an app can read data but not write it.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = [""
      , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
      , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
      , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
      ,   'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'
      , "https://mail.google.com/"
      , " https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('project-id-[hiddenID].json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

sht2 = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[hiddenID]')

worksheet = sht2.get_worksheet(0)

val = worksheet.acell('B1').value
print(val)



worksheet.update_acell('B6', 'Bingo!')
```

It's the last line that calls the error

```
APIError: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I've tried giving the API owner access, but I guess I'm doing the permissions wrong.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you changed scopes but not refreshed authorization? (i.e. deleted any local cached credentials)

Comment: when you say local cached credential, would that be local files, like credentials.json? I deleted every other json file which had credentials and it didnt work. Am i taking your suggestion correctly?

Comment: The file that stores your client ID and secret (or equivalent) does not need to be deleted--the file that stores an access or refresh token does. The tokens are not valid for new or different scope authorizations. Also, make sure you have shared the document with the service account.

Answer (score 3):

This was solved by adding the same email on the account as an editor on the document. Simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

go to console of google cloud.

enable google drive and sheet apis

visit the https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

create a service account

Give all the required permissions

click done

you will find a email in credential page in Service Account:
- copy the email provided in that like :
shee......iam.gservunt.com

Go to your spreadsheet and click Share in the top right corner.

send the invitation in it with this email

and Done